# Set player position

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Ex. You want to move your character to coordinate 0,-10,1 but you don't want to add location normally. When you touch an item, i want to SET the position to those coordinates. The motion actuator can't do it even though character motion has a SET setting that doesn't work correctly. What should I type for Python to achieve this? Also, is it possible to set an object's location to match another object's location?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the location like this:

```
object = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]  # for example
object.location = ((0,-10,1))
```

or

```
object.location = bpy.data.objects["Sphere"].location
```

to match this objects location to the one of i.g. a sphere in your scene.